# Google indexed the redirection link of my website

Tags: seo

I'm trying to fix a couple of problems of SEO on my website, the thing is that my website has several languages and the links of each language goes like this:

**Enlgish version:** `www.example.com/en`

**Spanish version**: `www.example.com/es`

**"Default" version**: `www.example.com` (This on redirects to the English version)

And when I search for it on Google the results show two links the default version, and the Spanish version but what I want to show on Google is only the one that matches the language of the user, in my case Spanish.

I have already added the canonical and alternate links, and the results are the exact same, is there other changes that I should do that will help Google to show the correct language of each user?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check hreflang implementation:

- Ensure your hreflang tags are valid and implemented consistently across all language versions.
- Use the full URL path within the hreflang attributes for each language version.
- Validate your hreflang implementation using Google's hreflang Tag Tester tool: https://hreflang.org/
- In Google Search Console, under the "International targeting" section, specify the default language of your website and configure preferred language settings for each version.
- Monitor the Crawl Stats report to see how Google is crawling and indexing your different language versions.